# jquery redirect after form submission

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2

I use codeignitor. Following is the jquery code I use for login form validation.

```
            $("#login_form").validate({
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) { },// Disable error messages
                debug:true,
                rules: {
                    username: 
                    {
                        required: true,
                        remote: 
                        {
                            url: "http://localhost/my_site/index_page/validate_username_password",
                            type: "post",
                            data: {
                            password: function(){ return $("#password").val(); } //Password is sent alongside the username
                            }
                        }
                    },
                password:{required:true}
                },
                highlight: function(username, errorClass) 
                {
                    $(username).fadeOut(function() 
                    {
                        $(username).fadeIn();
                    });
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) // CALLED ON SUCCESSFUL VALIDATION
                {
                    window.location.replace='http://localhost/my_site/index_page';
                }
            });
```

By this code, after success validation, I am expecting my page to get redirected to

```
http://localhost/my_site/index_page
```

but it is not.

I use codeignitor.

Comment: Is submitHandler fired? Any error in console/network tab?

Comment: Submithandler fired. I used alert() to check it. No error in cosole/ Network tab.

Comment: What about using instead: `window.location.replace('...');` ?!

Comment: What authentication model is that? Are you sure the username/password is being returned successful?

Comment: ^Wolff, window.location.replace('...'); worked thank you!!!

Comment: user1641165,  Authentication model? I just verified them in database, and returned json true.

Comment: @Karthiprime So feel free to accept answer below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.replace()` is a function, use it as:

```
window.location.replace('http://localhost/my_site/index_page');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript) and see the proposed solutions.

Before jumping to any conclusion make sure `submitHandler: function(form) {}` is indeed fired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use

```
document.location='http://localhost/my_site/index_page';
```

instead of

```
window.location.replace='http://localhost/my_site/index_page';
```

in your code...

Comment: but that will add new entry in browser history